# Autoscroll not working when child control exceeds 32767 width

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, scrollbar, panel

I am using a panel and auto scroll for printing texts in bitmap Editor(Bitmap Editor - a control created by me for printing texts in ellipses). My issue is that the texts are simply ignored or is not showing in the bitmap editor when the width of bitmap editor exceeds 32767 size.

Is that possible to use auto scroll  other than in panels or please anyone help me to solve this.

Thanks a lot for helping me on this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At lasts I got the reason for the error mentioned above.

LPARAM -  A Data type of Windows used to pass message parameters to Windows Procedure.
          It is a 32 bit pointer which passes message as two parts
          i.e in High order(First 16 bits of 32 bits) and 
                 Low order(Second 16 bits of 32 bits).

```
      Where 
           High order is used to pass the height of the control and
           Low order is used to pass the width of the control
```

So if the height or width of the control exceeds 32762size, it shows error
because

```
32767 is the highest number that can be represented in a signed 16bit integer.
```